# Powershell commands wants to open file

Tags: powershell, msbuild

I'm trying to run a PS script via my MSBuild, but whenever the build executes, we get a application dialog pop up. I have researched this, and it would seem that I am the first person to have gotten this; which I highly doubt.

My "`csproj`" file has the following `<Target />`:

```
  <Target Name="PreBuild" BeforeTargets="PreBuildEvent">
    <Exec Command="%WINDIR%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command &quot;&amp; {$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\updatebuildversion.ps1}&quot;" />
  </Target>
```

Has anyone else run into this problem?

Comment: So do you still have a question then?

Comment: Please either delete the question or (better yet) answer your own question!

Answer (score 0):

I change the command to exclude the `$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)` and replaced that with `.\updatebuildversion.ps1` and this works. Very weird :?

So the `<Target />` will look like this:

```
  <Target Name="PreBuild" BeforeTargets="PreBuildEvent">
    <Exec Command="%WINDIR%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command &quot;&amp;{.\updatebuildversion.ps1}&quot;" />
  </Target>
```